# Kafka-Connect : Can source and sink use same topic?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using Kafka-MongoDB-Connect where

> 1. Source is Debezium Connector
> 2. Sink is Kafka-MongoDB-Connector by MongoDB

Can I use same topic and MongoDB collection for both Source and Sink Connector? Will it cause messages to go in infinite loop?

Comment: Do you want to sink to the same collection (which is used for sourcing)?

Comment: Yes, requirement is to get one database say DB1 (another system) changes into kafka using CDC and then using kafka connect get these changes into another DB day DB2

Comment: Does your pipeline look like this? `DB1 —(Kafka Connect Source)—> Kafka —(Kafka Connect Sink)—> DB2`.

Comment: yes! thats the design

Comment: At this rate it's an absolutely common use case. Sink connector doesn't need to know about the source connector (just about Kafka topic) and vice versa. Kafka topic is the core of your pipeline

Comment: ...and I see in this case we do not need to source and sink same collection, so what if design is like this ---- "updates and consumer ->DB1 <->kafka  <-updates and Consumer",  Just a question and trying to experiment. What if source and sink is same DB and topic is same too

Comment: it work db logs, so if you read something from source and write it back to target (which is the same source) it will keep on writing infinitely to logs and hence it will go to infinite loop. But why would anyone ever do that.